# ¿Como sumar el contenido de un input a un dato en una tabla de MySQL en php?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una base de datos en mi computadora principal llena de registros de diferentes productos, necesitaba realizar una busqueda y luego de que se encontrara el producto mediante el código de barras se procediera a sumarle una cantidad introducida por un usuario, la parte de la conexión a la base de datos me funciona e igual el de buscar, la parte de la suma es la que no logro concretar. en mi buscador tengo este código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Buscador</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="buscador.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" name="palabra" placeholder="¿Qué esta buscando?">
        <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
    </form>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['palabra'])){
            require_once "php/connect.php";
            require_once "procesos/buscar.php";
        }
    ?>
     <form action="buscador.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" name="conteo" placeholder="Cantidad">
        <input type="submit" value="Sumar">
        </form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['conteo'])){
                require_once "php/connect.php";
                require_once "procesos/conteo.php";
            }
    ?>
 </body>
</html>`
```

En el conteo.php tengo este codigo:

```
<?php
$conteo=$_POST['conteo'];
$palabra=$_POST['palabra'];
$query= "UPDATE inventario_principal SET conteo = conteo + '%$conteo%' WHERE codigo = '%$palabra%'";
```

Pero aun no logro hacer que funcione, soy bastante nuevo en php y quisiera saber cual es el problema. El error que me da es que la variable "Palabra" no tiene indice pero creo que se declara en el primer form.

Comment: No necesitas los simbolos de `%`

Comment: *El error que me da es que la variable "Palabra" no tiene indice pero creo que se declara en el primer form.*  Si te dice que no encuentra un valor para `$_POST['palabra']` significa que no estás posteando los datos al archivo correcto, por ejemplo, en el `action` de ambos formularios tú tienes el archivo `buscador.php`, que será el archivo que se ejecutará cuando el form sea enviado. El código que te está fallando está en `conteo.php`... Este archivo no podrá recibir `$_POST['palabra']`. Luego, para que la query funcione, debes tomar en cuenta lo que te dice @alanfcm en su comentario.

Comment: Especifica en que evento ocurre el error, tienes dos formularios, uno para Buscar y otro para sumar, especifica donde es y en que linea de codigo

Comment: Este es el error
**Notice: Undefined index: palabra in C:\xampp\htdocs\inventario\procesos\conteo.php on line 3**

Esta es la linea 3
`$palabra=$_POST['palabra'];`

Comment: @JeffreyCedaño Obviamente en **conteo.php** nunca va a existir `$_POST['palabra']` ya que en el formulario que envías a conteo.php no existe ningún `input name="palabra"`. Por otro lado te recomiendo verificar con `isset` las variables que esperas recibir. También has de tener en cuenta que **tu código es vulnerable a inyección SQL**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se produce porque tendrías que añadir un input en el segundo formulario para el campo palabra, ya que cada formulario es independiente uno del otro.

Por otro lado, creo que puedes plantearlo de otra forma y ahorrar un par de lineas de código, llamando directamente al fichero PHP desde el formulario.

En tu formulario añade el fichero "conteo.php" en action. También debes añadir un input para la variable palabra.

```
<form action="conteo.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
 <input type="text" name="palabra" placeholder="¿Qué esta buscando?">
 <input type="text" name="conteo" placeholder="Cantidad">
 <input type="submit" value="Sumar">
</form>
```

Edita el fichero conteo.php para incluir la conexión a la base de datos y realiza la consulta desde ahí.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 include_once 'conexion.php';

 $conteo=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['conteo']);
 $palabra=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['palabra']);

 $query= "UPDATE inventario_principal SET conteo = conteo + '$conteo' WHERE
 codigo = '$palabra'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
} else {
 header("Location: ./index.php");
 exit();
}
```

De esta forma debería funcionar. La variable $conn procede de conexion.php, puedes adaptarlo según como establezcas la conexión en tu proyecto.

Comment: Creo que no entendiste lo que necesito, primero se tiene que localizar un dato por medio de un codigo de barras, al buscarlo y entontrarlo se debe mostrar el nombre y la cantidad (esta parte ya la tengo completa) y que salga otro form que lo que va a hacer es al ponerle una cantidad x la sume a la columna del dato que se acaba de encontrar, no sé si me explico bien.

Comment: Tras realizar la búsqueda puedes enviar el resultado en una variable en la URL y recuperarla con $_GET para saber cual es el dato que has localizado y poder usarlo.Creo que sería de ayuda si incluyes tu fichero buscador.php y buscar.php .